# Redshift SQL - Count Sequences of Repeating Values Within Groups

Tags: sql, count, amazon-redshift

I have a table that looks like this:

```
| id |      date_start     |    gap_7_days   |
| -- | ------------------- | --------------- |
|  1 | 2021-06-10 00:00:00 |        0        |
|  1 | 2021-06-13 00:00:00 |        0        |
|  1 | 2021-06-19 00:00:00 |        0        |
|  1 | 2021-06-27 00:00:00 |        0        |
|  2 | 2021-07-04 00:00:00 |        1        |
|  2 | 2021-07-11 00:00:00 |        1        |
|  2 | 2021-07-18 00:00:00 |        1        |
|  2 | 2021-07-25 00:00:00 |        1        |
|  2 | 2021-08-01 00:00:00 |        1        |
|  2 | 2021-08-08 00:00:00 |        1        |
|  2 | 2021-08-09 00:00:00 |        0        |
|  2 | 2021-08-16 00:00:00 |        1        |
|  2 | 2021-08-23 00:00:00 |        1        |
|  2 | 2021-08-30 00:00:00 |        1        |
|  2 | 2021-08-31 00:00:00 |        0        |
|  2 | 2021-09-01 00:00:00 |        0        |
|  2 | 2021-08-08 00:00:00 |        1        |
|  2 | 2021-08-15 00:00:00 |        1        |
|  2 | 2021-08-22 00:00:00 |        1        |
|  2 | 2021-08-23 00:00:00 |        1        |
```

For each ID, I check whether consecutive `date_start` values are 7 days apart, and put a 1 or 0 in `gap_7_days` accordingly.

I want to do the following (using Redshift SQL only):

1. Get the length of each sequence of consecutive 1s in `gap_7_days` for each ID

Expected output:

```
| id |      date_start     |    gap_7_days   | sequence_length |
| -- | ------------------- | --------------- | --------------- |
|  1 | 2021-06-10 00:00:00 |        0        |                 |
|  1 | 2021-06-13 00:00:00 |        0        |                 |
|  1 | 2021-06-19 00:00:00 |        0        |                 |
|  1 | 2021-06-27 00:00:00 |        0        |                 |
|  2 | 2021-07-04 00:00:00 |        1        |        6        |
|  2 | 2021-07-11 00:00:00 |        1        |        6        |
|  2 | 2021-07-18 00:00:00 |        1        |        6        |
|  2 | 2021-07-25 00:00:00 |        1        |        6        |
|  2 | 2021-08-01 00:00:00 |        1        |        6        |
|  2 | 2021-08-08 00:00:00 |        1        |        6        |
|  2 | 2021-08-09 00:00:00 |        0        |                 |
|  2 | 2021-08-16 00:00:00 |        1        |        3        |
|  2 | 2021-08-23 00:00:00 |        1        |        3        |
|  2 | 2021-08-30 00:00:00 |        1        |        3        |
|  2 | 2021-08-31 00:00:00 |        0        |                 |
|  2 | 2021-09-01 00:00:00 |        0        |                 |
|  2 | 2021-08-08 00:00:00 |        1        |        4        |
|  2 | 2021-08-15 00:00:00 |        1        |        4        |
|  2 | 2021-08-22 00:00:00 |        1        |        4        |
|  2 | 2021-08-23 00:00:00 |        1        |        4        |
```

2. Get the number of sequences for each ID

Expected output:

```
| id |    num_sequences    |
| -- | ------------------- |
|  1 |          0          |
|  2 |          3          |
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the number of sequences, just look at the previous value.  When the current value is "1" and the previous is `NULL` or `0`, then you have a new sequence.

So:

```
select id,
       sum( (gap_7_days = 1 and coalesce(prev_gap_7_days, 0) = 0)::int ) as num_sequences
from (select t.*,
             lag(gap_7_days) over (partition by id order by date_start) as prev_gap_7_days
      from t
     ) t
group by id;
```

If you actually want the lengths of the sequences, as in the intermediate results, then ask a *new* question.  That information is not needed for this question.